# remember the client is mobile or pc with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

Things like this.When people open our website using mobile phone.We have two site,one is `example.com` and other is for mobile client `xxx.mobile.com`.Though Nginx I lead different client to the right site.

But everything can't be perfect.If one people using a unknown client,what he will do on the site.

So I need to give him some advance, like a link or button to guide him to the right place where he can go.The `User-agent` can't change, what can I do to remember the status.I think using the session.But with php and javascript, I lost myself. What can I do to cheat the Nginx server to redirect the right place, and when it comes again, I can recognize the client and quick guide it.Or with the language javascript to rewrite `location.href`, and direct it to the new place.